# iPhone X launch image

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have added the Launch image of `1125px*2436px` for iPhone X to get rid of black space at the top and bottom. However, adding so shifted the view to the left. All the textfields , buttons in the view are moved a little to the left. My app was developed without storyboards and autolayout.
iPhone 7 screenshot
[image]

iPhone X screen
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

xib view[image]

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Comment: Would you please show some code that how you placed a view in the view?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I placed the textfields in xib. And my app was not using constraints

Comment: If you are not using Constraints then you have to use view frame right?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed do u mean I have to right separate view frame for iPhone X? Please see my edit how it looks in iphone 7

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Plz check

Comment: Please share code not the screen shot.

Comment: If you want your UI elements to adjust based on device size (get wider / narrower / taller / shorter / keep dimensions but center in view / etc), then you either need to write code to change the frames or --- and this is a ***MUCH*** better option --- use auto-layout constraints.

Comment: FYI - The use of Launch Images is no longer supported as of iOS 13. You need to switch to using a Launch Screen storyboard.

Comment: @rmaddy But my project is using xib's not storyboard. What I have to do in this case?

Comment: You need a Launch screen storyboard. That's true for otherwise completely code-only projects, apps that only use storyboards, or anything in between, including those using xibs.